# Flexbox: span with a link breaks in two line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is that the span, where inside there's `a link`, breaks on two lines. This is the code:

```
 <div id="formvox">
   <span>
     <span id="momentaneo"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i> Caricamento in corso...</span>
     <span id="force">Prova ad attendere qualche minuto altrimenti <a href="#">iscriviti di nuovo</a></span>
   </span>
 </div>
```

And this css:

```
#formvox {     
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;    
}


#momentaneo {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;   
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}


#force {
  display: flex;     
  justify-content: center;    
}
```

This is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ek7z718n/

I don't understand why if width of window is very small, the span `#force` breaks on two line. Maybe the problem is `a` ?
I tried many times to solve it but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `display:flex;` on the `#force` span.

This is occurring because the span is trying to fit all children onto one line, hence why the a will not go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

it is forced on to the next line because you have width of 100% for #momentaneo so it takes up the full parent width and then the other element if forced to the next line

you might change width:100% to max-width:100%